# Как сделать меню в Visual C++?

Tags: winapi, mfc, visual-c++

Подскажите, как сделать меню в Visual C++ (надо, чтобы примерно как в делфи было, то есть форма, кнопки и другие элементы). Как это реализовать на Си? Или подскажите, в какой литературе это есть.

Answer (score 3):

Первым делом установить [Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP). Затем, используя мастер проектов, [создать](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/4457htyc(v=VS.100).aspx) подходящее. Если выбрать диалоговое приложение, то будет почти как в Delphi: форма, кнопки и так далее.

Comment: Ух ты, а я не знал, что она такое умеет))) Думал, такое только на C#)))

Answer (score 1):

Добавить ресурс "меню", дать ему идентификатор, потом в диалоговом окне, котором хочешь добавить меню, в свойствах этого окна выбрать нужный ID меню ресурса.

Answer (score 1):

Для создания полноценных оконных приложений подразумевается наличие всех привычных элементов управления, таких как: кнопки, бегунки, строки состояния, переключатели и т.д.; требуется наличие полноценной среды разработки, IDE, как уже было сказано выше, - Visual C++.

Размещение таких элементов в рабочем окне проекта, как собственно и создание самого окна, сложностей не вызывает, а вот смысловое наполнение Ваших элементов потребует немного дополнительных знаний и навыков, определенных особенностями самой среды разработки, таких, например, как работа посредством посылки сообщений между элементами и обработка их через карту сообщений, обработка нажатия кнопок мыши, отслеживание местоположения курсора и т.д. В общем, наряду с "базовыми" знаниями стандарта языка, необходимо также изучить специфику и методы работы в самой среде разработки, особенности различных элементов и принципы их взаимосвязи. Свежие версии сред разработки, такие как Visual Studio 2010, к слову, предоставляют достаточно богатый набор вспомогательных сервисов, которые заметно облегчают задачу проектировки и создания современного приложения.

Answer (score 0):

WinAPI, также можно попробовать на C# начать писать.

Answer (score 0):

Пытался на C++ в [SFML](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1KJHD2-N0M&t=91s)сделать

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

#include <windows.h>

//#include <MMSystem.h>
//#include <Iostream>

using namespace sf;
int x, y, s;
int main()


 {
RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(350, 490), "MENU");
while (window.isOpen())

{   sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

  if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Up)){
        s = s + 1; 

        if (s = 0){ s = 3; }
        if (s = 4){ s = 1; }
        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);


        if (s = 1){

            Texture menu1texture; // пехаем проверку внутри нажатия чтоб 
 исключить дискотеку спрайтов
            menu1texture.loadFromFile("C:/111/MY_GAME/MENU001.JPG");
            Sprite menu1sprite;
            menu1sprite.setTexture(menu1texture);
            menu1sprite.setTextureRect(IntRect(0, 0, 350, 490));//получили 
 нужный нам прямоугольник с меню
            //herosprite.setPosition(0, 0);  //выводим спрайт в позицию x y 
            window.draw(menu1sprite);
            window.display();
            menu1sprite.setPosition(0, 0);  //выводим спрайт в позицию x y
        }


        if (s = 2){

            Texture menu2texture;
            menu2texture.loadFromFile("C:/111/MY_GAME/MENU002.JPG");
            Sprite menu2sprite;
            menu2sprite.setTexture(menu2texture);
            window.draw(menu2sprite);
            window.display();
            menu2sprite.setPosition(0, 0);  //выводим спрайт в позицию x y
        }


        if (s = 3){
            Texture menu3texture;

            menu3texture.loadFromFile("C:/111/MY_GAME/MENU003.JPG");
            Sprite menu3sprite;
            menu3sprite.setTexture(menu3texture);
            window.draw(menu3sprite);
            window.display();
            menu3sprite.setPosition(0, 0);  //выводим спрайт в позицию x y
                        }
        Sleep(1000);

    }







         if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Down)){ 
    s = s - 1;
    if (s = 0){ s = 3; }
    if (s = 4){ s = 1; }
    window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        if (s = 1){

        Texture menu1texture;  // пехаем проверку внутри нажатия чтоб 
        исключить дискотеку спрайтов
        menu1texture.loadFromFile("C:/111/MY_GAME/MENU001.JPG");
        Sprite menu1sprite;
        menu1sprite.setTexture(menu1texture);
        menu1sprite.setTextureRect(IntRect(0, 0, 350, 490));//получили 
     нужный нам прямоугольник с меню
        //herosprite.setPosition(0, 0);  //выводим спрайт в позицию x y 
        window.draw(menu1sprite);
        window.display();
        menu1sprite.setPosition(0, 0);  //выводим спрайт в позицию x y
    }


    if (s = 2){

        Texture menu2texture;
        menu2texture.loadFromFile("C:/111/MY_GAME/MENU002.JPG");
        Sprite menu2sprite;
        menu2sprite.setTexture(menu2texture);
        window.draw(menu2sprite);
        window.display();
        menu2sprite.setPosition(0, 0);  //выводим спрайт в позицию x y
    }


    if (s = 3){
        Texture menu3texture;

        menu3texture.loadFromFile("C:/111/MY_GAME/MENU003.JPG");
        Sprite menu3sprite;
        menu3sprite.setTexture(menu3texture);
        window.draw(menu3sprite);
        window.display();
        menu3sprite.setPosition(0, 0);  //выводим спрайт в позицию x y

    }

    Sleep(1000);
}









 }



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Извиняюсь,  но хотел бы уточнить, а чем ваша попытка завершилась?

Comment: Созданы 3 текстуры - в каждом пункте меню выводится при нажаии спрайт соответствующего меню с уже нажатой кнопкой - 3 варианта спрайта меню - 3 пункта меню